# How to make PHP variables queired from SQL table to pass to "iframe" as url?

Tags: php, html, mysql, iframe

I have the script below. The resulting record from array is okay except that when I use it in "iframe" as auto url, it always point to the first record, which is accounting.php.

```
$sql="SELECT DISTINCT(b.dept_name) as title, count(dept_name) AS count, REPLACE( b.dept_name, ' ', '-' ) AS urlink FROM position a, department b WHERE a.pos_dept=b.dept_code GROUP BY b.dept_name HAVING count > 1";

if ($result=mysqli_query($link,$sql))
{
// Fetch one and one row

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{
$dept=$row[0];
$count=$row[1];
$urlink=strtolower($row[2].'.php');

echo '<a href="#popup" class="popup-link">'.$dept.' - ( '.$count.'     '.$urlink.')</a><p><div class="popup-wrapper" id="popup"><div class="popup-container"><iframe src="'.$urlink.'" width="100%" height="500"></iframe><a class="popup-close" href="#closed">X</a></div></div>';

}

mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

I tried to run without the "iframe" to debug and the $urlink is correct and changing as follows:(values of $dept, $count, $urlink respectively)

- Accounting, (2),accounting.php
- Administrative, (2),administrative.php
- Engineering, (2), engineering.php
- Food and Beverage, (11), food-and-beverage.php
- Hospitality, (16), hospitality.php
- Information System, (2), information-system.php
- Warehouse, (4), warehouse.php

*Note: the $urlink above is giving the correct data. It's changing and correspond to the dept but when use in "iframe" always point to accounting.php.*

How can I pass the $urlink or $row[2] to "iframe" as its url so it can self generate the url of each "iframe"? (total of 7 iframes with different url)

Thanks in advance,

Comment: By using session variables

Comment: Hi mulquin, new to php, can i see sample script based on the above on how session variables can capture variables resulted from while loop?